# QT applications does support Unicode

Tags: linux, terminal, gentoo, unicode, qt

My system is Gentoo amd64, and the desktop environment is Xfce4. So far, most applications works well, except the terminal and QT-family applications.

The Chromium,Thunar, Thunderbird and many other applications supports Unicode very well. I can see and input Chinese.

But the terminal does not support displaying/inputting Chinese. I tried to set the LANG and LC_CTYPE variables, set the fonts...nothing works.

My SMPlayer and VLC uses QT based UI, and both of the cannot play the video if the path/file name contains non-ASCII characters. But they works well otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my problem has been solved. I mistakenly removed qt3support from my system...after I add it back, the terminal can display Chinese, and the players can play the videos correctly.